# How to encrypt dates using format preserving encryption and avoid collisions

Tags: format-preserving

I'm encrypting with an FPE algorithm in C#.  What I did is convert the date I want to encrypt to the day of year value and a year value like so.

```
string input = "1901-01-01";
DateTimeOffset parsedDateOffset = new DateTimeOffset();
bool parsed = false;
parsed = DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact(input, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, out parsedDateOffset);

if(parsed){

    DateTime dtNew = new DateTime(parsedDateOffset.Year, parsedDateOffset.Month, parsedDateOffset.Day);
    int dayOfYear = dtNew.DayOfYear;
    int yyyy = parsedDateOffset.Year;

// Then I encrypt the day of year separate from the year

    int encodedDay = FE11.Encrypt(365, dayOfYear, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input.ToString()), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("0"));
    int encodedYear= FE11.Encrypt(2015 - 1901, yyyy, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input.ToString()), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("0"));

// Then combine them together again taking into account leap year

     DateTime encodedDate = new DateTime((int)encodedYear, 1, 1).AddDays((int)encodedDay - 1);;
     if (DateTime.IsLeapYear((int)encodedYear))
     {
         encodedDate.AddDays(1);
     }   
}
```

However I'm encountering duplicate dates (i.e. for two plaintext dates result in the same encrypted date)  But with format preserving encryption this should not be the case, and I know it is because of the way I am emcrypting the year separate from the day of year.

Does anyone have any suggestion to overcome this?  I have tried introducing a tweak but the problem persists.

Ideally I would like to encrypt only one value.  But encrypting the day of year alone still requires me to place it in the context of a year when presenting the final encrypted result.

Are there other date representation besides day of year that might be useful?

**EDIT:**  The FPE library I am using at this time is called DotFPE located here https://dotfpe.codeplex.com/ (which is supposedly a port of the Format Preserving module of Botan Crypto)

Comment: What FPE library are you using? Can you give us a link to it?

Comment: @mikeazo ok, added that detail at the end of my original post

Comment: Can you provide some sample outputs? Are the values duplicate right after the call to ```Encrypt``` or not until you call ```AddDays```?

Comment: Also, when I look at the code, ```Encrypt``` takes 4 parameters, not 3 like you show in your example code. What am I missing?

Comment: @mikeazo sorry it was the key, I updated the post.  BTW I'm using the original date as the key using Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input.ToString())  since I only care to encrypt one way, no need to decrypt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, in the comments, you state that

> I'm using the original date as the key

This is the reason for the duplicate dates. The encryption is entirely deterministic for a fixed key. When you change the key, however, it is not. So it is entirely plausible that encrypting the number `215` with the key `215` could result in the same ciphertext as encrypting the number `10` with the key `10`. But, encrypting the numbers `215` and `10` each with the same key, say `111`, should be guaranteed to result in different ciphertexts (assuming you are not using the tweak, or using a fixed tweak).

If you had a fixed, random key, then you should get different ciphertexts. Adding in a random, per-message "tweak" can also cause this behavior.

So you can fix this "problem" by just using the same key everywhere and no tweak. This does, however, **scare me**. You are using deterministic encryption in an application that has a fairly small domain. Could make you vulnerable to frequency attacks, or other attacks, depending on the exact application.

Comment: I probably wouldn't use a single key for everything, since my goal by changing the key for each input was to make it difficult to decipher.  I think I'm going to try ponchos suggestion and use the Timespan in days since a start date, that way I encrypt only one value instead of two separate.

Comment: @erotavlas I really like his idea too and would recommend that. If you use the date as the key, however, you will still have a chance of getting duplicates. Depending on the application, that may not be a bad thing, however.

Comment: I'm getting almost the exact same number of duplicates (over 15000) using a Timespan in days as my initial method.  When I cycle through every day from 1901-01-01 until 2015-12-31.  Does this sound right?  I expected every input value to result in a unique output value.  My key is Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(elapsedDays.ToString()) and my tweak is Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("0"))  and my modulus is days since 1901-01-01

Comment: If you use the ```Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("0"))``` as the key, do you get any duplicates? I'm not sure if 15000 is the expected number. I'd have to work out the math.

Comment: I don't think that over 15000 duplicates would be out of the ordinary. [Here](http://pastebin.com/hZLABedb) is some python code I wrote that generates 42003 random numbers between 0 and 42003 (inclusive) and counts how many duplicates there are.  Running it, I was getting around 15500 duplicates.

Comment: @erotavlas: actually, there's no need to change the key for every date; that's what the tweak is for.

Comment: @poncho, my guess is erotavlas is trying to do [this](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/24287/706).

Comment: @erotavlas, I asked [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/27370/formula-for-the-number-of-expected-collisions) to get a better answer for you.

Comment: @mikeazo yes your guess is correct, I was aiming for something along the lines of the cryptographic hash that can preserve length and format.  I think I understand your explanation of why I get duplicates.  I'm just not sure what the correct way to solve the problem is and also produce a result that cryptographically secure.

Comment: @erotavlas this site would be a good place to ask. Make sure you ask about the higher level problem you are facing. Don't start with a possible solution.

Comment: @mikeazo I realized something else, I'm using this FPE to encrypt words and names according to this post [here](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/24225/12377), but I'm doing the same thing with they key, using each input plaintext as a new key.  I haven't run a test yet, but I'm guessing there would be collisions as well. However since the range of values possible is much larger and input strings change in length (modulus changes for word of different length)  I'm guessing duplicates wouldn't occur as frequently as with this case of the dates? any thoughts?

Comment: @erotavias, the longer the input the better.

Comment: @mikeazo sorry one more question - What part of the algorithm inside the FPE results in this behaviour of collisions when you use different key each time? (if the answer would be too long, I can post a new question about it tomorrow)

Comment: @erotavlas it has little to do with FPE  and everything to do with the output space. It is the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)

Answer (score 3):

One potential reason you might be running into duplicates is if you encrypt 'December 31' of a leap year; that makes it day 366, and that's out of range for your FPE method.

The obvious way to address this (and encrypt both days and years together) would be to convert the value into "days since January 1, 1901", encrypt that as a value between 0 and 42003 (the number of days between January 1, 1901 and December 31, 2015), and then convert that back into the standard format.

Comment: Actually I corrected for leap year.  My modulus is set to 365 to yield an encrypted value between 0 - 364 (or 1 - 365) Once I obtain the day value, if the year value I use is a leap year according to DateTime.IsLeapYear() method I add an extra day to the result.  Not sure if that is correct way, but it did seem to work.

Comment: @erotavlas, if you are always adding 1, doesn't that make January 1 of leap years impossible?

Comment: oops, yeah that's right.  I'd need to change the modulus instead, have one encryption that gives leap years and another for regular years.

Comment: @erotavlas the nice thing about using this encoding is that you don't have to work around leap year corner cases.

Comment: And, it doesn't leak if two encrypted dates are from the same year; if the attacker sees 'Jan 23, 1932' and 'November 19, 1932', with your encoding, they don't know the year, but they can deduce both were from the same one.