# Formula for the number of expected collisions

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, birthday-attack

Say we have a hash function that produces $n$ bit outputs. From the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) that after around $\sqrt{2^n}$ different inputs to the has function, we can expect a collision.

Say instead that we have $m$ outputs. How many collisions can we expect in those $m$ outputs?

If there are $k$ inputs that all have the same output, we say there are $\binom{k}{2}$ collisions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The expected number of collisions (assuming that the hash function can be modeled as a random function) is precisely $2^{-n}\binom{m}{2}$; that is, the expected number of pairs of values $x \ne y$ with $H(x) = H(y)$ (and so, to answer Ricky's question, $H(x) = H(y) = H(z)$ would count as three collisions).

The reasoning is the obvious one; there are $\binom{m}{2}$ separate pairs, and each pair has a probability $2^{-n}$ of colliding (and hence has an expected number of collisions of $2^{-n}$), and the expected sum of a set of probabilistic values is the sum of each individual value's expectation.  The probabilities are not independent (for example, if $H(x)=H(y)$ and $H(y)\ne H(z)$, we know that $H(x) \ne H(z)$); it turns out that the expected sum doesn't depend on independence.

Comment: @mikeazo Does that mean that [these tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack) are inaccurate in their estimates of the p=50% scenario or am I misunderstanding what these tables represent. It seems to me if the p=0.5 should occur when number of "perfectly random and normally distributed hashes" is 2^(n/2) then the 50% column should read: 256 for 16 bit hashes, 65536 for 32 bit hashes and so on? (Meta question: should I be raising this as a new question? I know my question is different but It just seemed really relevant to what's discussed here).

Comment: @IamNick did you find an answer to that question by any chance?

Comment: @rinat.io: I didn't see IamNick's question, however the answer is "those tables are addressing a different question than I did".  I looked at the expected (average) number of collisions; the table looked at "at what point do you get at least one collision with the specified probability".  The reason that an average of one collision doesn't occur precisely at $p=0.5$ is that you have a probability of having two collisions in the same collection; that bumps of the average, but doesn't change the probability of getting at least one collision

Comment: There seems to be some perplexing quirks to this formula, as I can verify it with real-world collisions for $n=32$ but *not* $n=16$. However, an alternate formula seems to be correct in this case: `n - m * (1 - ((m-1)/m) ^ n)`, where $m=2^{16}$ and $n=32421$ give $6845.466801931194 $. For reasons I don't understand, your binomial formula gives $8019.171295166015625$.