# Are there key collisions in AES-192, AES-256?

Tags: aes, block-cipher

Suppose we have a single, fixed plaintext block $p$ of 128 bits. Call the set of all possible 128 bit blocks $B$.

We could define fixed plaintext AES-128 as a function $f(k) \to B$ that takes a 128 bit key $k$ and outputs a 128 bit ciphertext block $c$.

As far as I know, AES-128 is a bijective function in this manner (is this assumption correct? **edit:** it is not). Additionally, the range spans $B$.

So how does AES with larger keys work? It must be a surjective function. What does this mapping look like? Are there, for every plaintext $p$, simply $2^{128}$ keys that map it to ciphertext $c$? Or is it unevenly distributed? Since the very same set must map $c$ back to $p$, it implies some sort of pattern in which bits are ignored/canceled out, dependent on the key.

Does any of this have any implications? Or are there no patterns here, and this is simply the way it is?

Comment: "As far as I know, AES-128 is a bijective function in this manner" It's almost certainly not. We'd expect a [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) for how many inputs map to a particular output. About 37% of the outputs should be unreachable for any given plaintext.

Comment: A cipher with a fixed plaintext mapping the key to the ciphertext behaves like a hash function, for which we already have a related question: [Are common cryptographic hashes bijective when hashing a single block of the same size as the output?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/301/are-common-cryptographic-hashes-bijective-when-hashing-a-single-block-of-the-sam)

Comment: Related, asked the other way around: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/30373/for-a-given-plaintext-ciphertext-pair-how-many-valid-keys-are-there-in-aes