# Is it possible for a given plaintext and ciphertext to have two different keys?

Tags: encryption, hash, aes, keys, collision-resistance

This has probably been asked before but for a given ciphertext and plaintext pair, is it possible to have two different keys producing said pair? Or there are no collisions in AES, unlike hashing algorithms such as SHA1, SHA256, etc?

Comment: Related question here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/30373/for-a-given-plaintext-ciphertext-pair-how-many-valid-aes-keys-are-there

Comment: There are no collisions in the output of *keyed*-AES as that is a permutation but of course it only allows for single input / output block. It shouldn't be possible for a secure hash function such as SHA-256 to **find** a collision even though there are a lot, SHA-1 has been broken for collision resistance.